# How to send Audio data manually using udp sockets

Tags: sockets, audio, networking, udp, voice

I am working on Video chat application using udp sockets,
iam able to capture raw audio data which is huge in size. as it is chat application I should be able to transfer this audio data contineously.

The problem is this audio data is huge so socket mtu is not allowing me to transfer this data.

I am finding out the way I can split up this data and send through sockets and capture them at other end and combined them to produce voice data.
Please guide me how using udp sockets

Answer (score 3):

With `UDP` you have to take care by yourself of transmission order (`UDP datagram` *number 1* could be received `AFTER` a `UDP datagram` *number 2*) and lost packets (`UDP` doesn't grant delivery of the datagram)

You should use `TCP` for big size transfers where the order of the packets matters.

About `MTU`, you don't have to care if it is smaller than the size of the data you're going to send. The OS will defragment it for you.

Just split up the data in `64k` blocks (maximum size allowed for a single `send()` call) and loop until your data is totally transmitted.

Comment: Thank you Davide Berra. could you provide me some example links on how to perform transmission order, and lost packets

Comment: Assuming you're programming in C language: [Sockets tutorial - TCP](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm)

Comment: thanks, Iam sending byte array of size 64K with c# udp socket, iam able to send without any exception but, the receiver socket not able get the data. am i missing anything?

Comment: Thank you very much Davide Berra i got it, the problem lies in my coading i set receiver socket's buffer size to 1024 so i didn't recieve any data.